# How to create a cumulative counter for sales in a financial year?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, counter, data-manipulation

My df looks like this.

```
Policy_No   Date
1           10/1/2020
2           20/2/2020
3           20/2/2020
4           23/3/2020
5           18/4/2020
6           30/4/2020
7           30/4/2020
```

I would like to create a cumulative counter of policies logged in different dates based on the financial year (April-March)

```
Date         Cum count of policies
10/1/2020    1
20/2/2020    3
23/3/2020    4
18/4/2021    1
30/4/2021    3
```

18th April 2021 being a new financial year, the counter starts from 0.
Can someone help solve this?

Comment: I'd say `cumcounter` probably can be understood as not the thing you intented, so I edited it to full phrase :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl thanks. If you know the solution that would also be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a function called [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) which does that:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Policy_No":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"Date":["10/1/2020","20/2/2020","20/2/2020","23/3/2020","18/4/2020","30/4/2020","30/4/2020"]})

print(df)
#0  1   10/1/2020
#1  2   20/2/2020
#2  3   20/2/2020
#3  4   23/3/2020
#4  5   18/4/2020
#5  6   30/4/2020
#6  7   30/4/2020

df.groupby("Date")["Policy_No"].count().cumsum()

#Date
#10/1/2020    1
#18/4/2020    2
#20/2/2020    4
#23/3/2020    5
#30/4/2020    7
```

If you want to do it for each financial year, I think you'll  need to create a dataframe for each financial year, use the above logic, and concat them at last:

```py
df = ... #dataframe
year_2020 = pd.to_datetime("01/04/2020")<= df["date"] < pd.to_datetime("01/04/2021")
df_2020 = df.loc[year_2020].groupby("date")["Policy_No"].count().cumsum()

year_2021 = pd.to_datetime("01/04/2021")<= df["date"] < pd.to_datetime("01/04/2022")
df_2021 = df.loc[year_2021].groupby("date")["Policy_No"].count().cumsum()

#concat at the end

df_total = pd.concat((df_2020,df_2021))
```

Of course if you cannot do the year logic (because there's to many), you can place it within a loop like:

```py
def get_financial_dates():
     """
      Some function that returns the start and end
      of each financial year
     """
     return date_start,date_end


df_total = pd.DataFrame() #initial dataframe

for date_start, date_end in get_financial_dates():
    idx = date_start <= df["date"] < date_end
    df_temp = df.loc[idx].groupby("date")["Policy_No"].count().cumsum()

    #concat at the end  
    df_total = pd.concat((df_total,df_temp))
```

Comment: the counter should restart every financial year I.e. 1st April it should start from 0

Comment: Aaah sorry, I missed that. I have updated my answer

Comment: yes I followed your first approach, created different dfs and concatenated them